# Why do we draw complete graphs equally spacing vertexes on a circumference

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

This is not a very mathematical question, however I was wondering why do we draw $K_n$ by equally spacing vertexes on a circle, like this:

[image]

In particular, I was looking for a property that describes that shape (however, currently I've not find any reference about that, and I think it's because usually the graphs are described as adjacency matrix, which can be represented as we want)

I'm asking this since I'm developing a force graph animation/algorithm, and this structure is never achieved by any function I can think of (I'm creating the graph minimizing a loss/objective function).

Currently $K_7$ reaches this state as "most stable":
[image]

Some notes:

- the loss function is not convex, therefore there are local minima, but they seem to create the same structure
- I've tried different loss function, and they all converge to a solution different from the first image

Comment: That picture is highly symmetrical and easy to think about mathematically: it's a regular $n$-gon with all its diagonals. That may explain the "why". There's no reason to expect that it minimizes your particular loss function.

Comment: @EthanBolker yes, however also the latter one is highly symmetric... apart from that, I was trying to understand if there is a property of that graph that allows to get it out of a random initialization

Comment: It should be noted that in your star-of-David diagram of $K_7$ it isn't quite clear that there is an arc $1\to 4$, because graphically it is covered by the arcs $1\to 7$ and $7\to 4$.

Comment: hi @SassatelliGiulio yes you are right, however I've waited for my algorithm to converge before taking the screenshot, but yes, it's a complete graph even though it's not too clear from the image itself

Comment: @Alberto Sinigaglia: OT, but if you are into visualizing graphs, you might find some interesting reads on [Graphviz's theory site](https://graphviz.org/theory/).

Comment: Let me amplify on @EthanBolker 's comment: the first picture highlights the permutation symmetry of the graph. Your optimization in fact _breaks_ this symmetry (as minimal solutions tend to do, there are entire disciplines of physics based on this), as it picks a specific node to be in the center. Any one of the nodes could have settled there  (based on initial conditions), but the connectivity is still completely symmetric.

Comment: @user619894 oh now it makes more sense